# javascript - localStorage - issue with a loop and message to display

Tags: javascript, loops, local-storage, addeventlistener, message

In the script below, I try to record in the bowser the name of the users who connect to my application. If it is the first time that a user connects, when he presses the "submit" button to connect to the application I want a message "Welcome" + name + "!
If the user has already connected (his name is already registered in the localStorage), when he presses the submit button, I want a "Welcome back" + name + "!

Thank you for the comments below, I tried to take them into account. When I run the updated code below, only welcome appear on the message. The name of the user is not included on the message. How can I modify my code to correct this problem?

Thank you in advance for your advice.

JS script:

```
let myButton = document.getElementById ("myButton");
let myText = document.getElementById ("username");

function store() {
    let n = 0;
    while (localStorage.getItem("username" + n)) {
        n++;
}
localStorage.setItem("username" + n, myText.value);
}  

function welcomeUsername(){
    let resultMessage = "Welcome "
    let n = 0;
    while (n) {
        let user = localStorage.getItem("username" + n); 
    if(myText.value != user){
        resultMessage += myText.value + "!";
        break;
    } else {
        resultMessage += "back" + myText.value + "!";n++;
        }
    }
 alert(resultMessage);  
   
 }
```

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br />
    <br /> 
    <div class ="login_card"></div> 
    <div class = "log_head">
    <h1>Login</h1> 
    </div>
    <div class = "log_body">
    <br />
<label for="uname"><b>Please enter your username below and click on submit:</b></label> <br>
<input type="text" value = "Enter username" onfocus = 'this.value =""' id = "username"> <br>
<br> <br>
<input type="button"  onClick="welcomeUsername();location.href ='/index';" value = "Submit" id = "myButton">
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why have a counter on username. Just use `localStorage.setItem("username", myText.value);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this part of your code has problem `let value = localStorage.getItem("username")`. you cant get any value from your localstorage since you set them `'username'+n`, that;s why your `if` statement always run.
can you try this: `while (n) {let user = localStorage.getItem("username" + n);       if (myText.value == user) {resultMessage += myText.value; break; } else {resultMessage += "back" + myText.value + "!"; n++; }}`

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
const btn = document.getElementById('myButton');

// get a welcome message
const welcomeText = (name) => {
  // store the name as an array type, initialize if it does not exist
  let names = localStorage.getItem('usernames');
  names = names == null ? [] : names;
  // check if the name exists and decide the welcome message according to the result
  if (names.includes(name)) {
    return `Welcome back ${name}`;
  } else {
    // update storage information
    names.push(name);
    localStorage.setItem('usernames', names);
    return `Welcome ${name}`;
  }
};

// send name and call method
const submit = () => {
  const name = document.getElementById('username').value;
  alert(welcomeText(name));
};

btn.addEventListener('click', submit);
```